# as3: unpack zip = faster than loading single images?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

by using external libraries you can also unpack a preloaded zip inside the swf.

but is that method faster than preloading one file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I've done some basic benchmarks, and implemented into a few projects, the answer is yes. Images are already compressed, so the performance gain has nothing  to do with file size. Actually the zip might even be larger in the end. The gain is in the number of HTTP requests that need to be made. Every http request evolves a fair bit of hand shaking, reducing 50 requests to one shows a major speed difference, one that grows as the number of images increases.

With text files, the difference is far greater, as you see compression too. One image by itself sees no benefit, only groups.

Sorry for typos, I'm on my phone.

**Edit:** I'll add the best solution seems to be storing bitmaps in a swf and loading that. Flash does some amazing compression, especially with PNGs.

**EDIT 2:** I've put up some simple tests as a [demo here](http://tyleregeto.com/entries/single/id/zipped-asset-loading-benchmark).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large number of images, it may be better to package them as a zip, packing efficiency will depend on the type of images you are using.

That said, there is often little gain in file size when zipping png or jpg images. If there is a good gain in file size, then the downloading time can be offset against the unzipping time.

So the easy answer is, *maybe*: compare file size of the zip vs the combined images, then profile an average unpack time. If you can get a fast unpack + file size gain, then it's worthwhile.

Don't forget to factor in the overhead of the unzip library in the SWF file.

Comment: thank you - would you say, that handling zip-files is a modern way that is also used by the general flash-industry, or is it unusual ?

Comment: Well anecdotally, I remember when un/zipping was first viable in AS3 and it was something that a number of developers were interested in using, however, in practical terms it was rarely useful. Generally speaking it's unlikely to give you any serious gain in experience delivery, since any filesize gains (which will likely be minimal) will be offset against the unpack time. Even in cases where zipping may be seen as a deployment plus, I would be skeptical. The one case I can see advantages in would be packaging XML or other plain text in zips, however, you'd need a lot to make it worthwhile.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the benefit of reducing the number of http requests. See my response, I've done some tests around this in the past.

Comment: @TylerEgeto, that's very true, reduction in HTTP requests is definitely a good case, if external asset counts are up in the double digits (esp. over 50) then zipping is a useful strategy, however, SWF compression of assets into a RSL are on par, or better then zipping.

Comment: Yes definitely. In the game development I work on we bundle collections of assets together by compiling them into a SWF(s). That is the best solution IMO.

Comment: (P.S. That's why I didn't mention http request reduction as a benefit of zipping, didn't want to provide a false positive. )